# SQL precisa de CAST para retornar valores em consulta

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Senhores eu gerencio uma aplicação *PHP* que usa banco de dados SQL Server 2008. Após uma migração de servidor do banco de dados as consultas só funcionam fazendo a conversão com *CAST* e selecionando um por um no *SELECT*.

Quando **não** utilizo o *CAST* recebo este erro.

> Warning: mssql_query(): message: Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or 
>   ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier.
>   (severity 16) in C:\Program Files (x86)\NetMake\v81\wwwroot\Site\teste-conexao.php on line 152
>   Warning: mssql_query(): Query failed in C:\Program Files (x86)\NetMake\v81\wwwroot\Site\teste-conexao.php
>   on line 152 Warning: mssql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Program Files 
>   (x86)\NetMake\v81\wwwroot\Site\teste-conexao.php on line 154*

Será que o servidor do Banco de Dados está com esse driver ODBC desatualizado?

O posso fazer para não ter de mudar todas as consultas da aplicação?

Abaixo exemplos dos códigos:

```
    ## Não funciona (Consultas Autuais)
    $sql="SELECT * FROM MinhaTabela";
    $resultado = mssql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        echo$row['CampoVarchar']."<br>";
    }

    ## Funciona 
    $sql="SELECT  CampoVarchar , CAST(CampoVarchar AS TEXT)  AS CampoVarchar FROM MinhaTabela";
    $resultado = mssql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        echo$row['CampoVarchar']."<br>";
    }
```

Comment: O driver `mssql_` é antigo se montar um código simples com as funções `sqlsrv_` tem o mesmo problema?

Comment: Opa rray, vou tentar aqui !

Comment: Deu certo, troquei a conexão que era mssql_connect e funcionou. Vou ter algum trabalho para mudar os drivers mais será muito menos evasivo do que mexer em consultas e assim já me livro desse driver obsoleto, muito obrigado @rray